# Unable to call an activity from another activity inside MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

First in MainActivity, when a button is pressed, I create a new intent and call it. Then, in the second intent, I create a new intent and call it when another button is pressed. I am able to call the intent from MainActivity, but unable to call the newly created intent from second activity.

Also, I created entry for all intents in AndroidManifest.xml.

The error coming is as follows :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asad.reflect/com.example.asad.reflect.Superclass}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.b1)
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,Callinterface.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(this,Callclass.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
}
```

Callclass.java

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textclass);
        className=et.getText().toString();
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Superclass.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.asad.reflect">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Callclass"
            android:label="Callclass"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Callinterface"
            android:label="Callinterface"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Superclass"
            android:label="Superclass"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>


        <!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: the error is in the superclass Activity... show us the relevant code there pls

Comment: Now,it's working fine.I was doing some mistakes while inflating listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to

```
else if(v.getId() == R.id.button2){
    //Run your button 2 Intent
}else if(v.getId() == R.id.button3){
    //Run Button 3 Intent
}
```

Comment: The problem was a NullPointerException. I don't think this solves that.

Comment: Okay then try rebuilding the project, cleaning it, and make sure that your button references are correct. If the other buttons work with the same code then this one should be no different

Comment: It isn't "my" project. I'm just a passer-by telling you your answer doesn't solve the problem.